# Trouble subscribing to turtlesim color sensor in a rostest

Tags: rostest, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
def callback(data):
    self.fail(data.data)
x = rospy.Subscriber("/turtlesim/turtle1/color_sensor",Color, callback)
rospy.spin()
```

Hi, The topic is subscribe and published but i can manage to display the content, if you have any idea thanks.I am using rostest and the master server is different than with roslaunch. (conflit or setup to do?). it's never leave the rospy.spin()

thanks for your answer, the topic is good. When it subscribe I get this so it should be okay. But the callback is never call. I think rostest is doing something i don't get. I run the same in listener.py(from tutorial) and it's work.

```
rostopic info /turtlesim/turtle1/color_sensor 

Type: turtlesim/Color

Publishers:   * /turtlesim/turtlesim_node (http://jsf-p-desktop:55631/)

Subscribers:   * /turtlesim_move_test (http://jsf-p-desktop:34016/)
```

okey , i checked the hztest.py and they use:

```
 sub = rospy.Subscriber(topic, rospy.AnyMsg, self.callback)
```

should I look for the use of self?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10260/trouble-subscribing-to-turtlesim-color-sensor-in-a-rostest/) by [gainerems](https://answers.ros.org/users/692/gainerems/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll be unable to connect with nodes that were launched under rostest since rostest uses port `22422` instead of `11311`. You will need to change the `ROS_MASTER_URI` to accommodate this, i.e.:

```
$> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://your-hostname:22422
```

This is described in more detail [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostest#Overview).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gainerems](https://answers.ros.org/users/692/gainerems/) on 2011-06-16**:
Thx, actually I run the test and in another terminal (with changing the host) with the listener it works. The problem is in the test script, I can't get topic data from their. It's look like I can subscribe but i can't "listen" in test script.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have a typo? You are subscribing to /tulesim..., but might want /turtlesim...

It is ok to have a separate roscore running.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostest does not run against the existing roscore.  Instead, it sets up its own ROS system.  Does your rostest start all of the nodes that you intend to test with?

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gainerems](https://answers.ros.org/users/692/gainerems/) on 2011-06-16**:
thx, i stoped roscore but it's still the same.